# MYSQL replace left join data with right join where equal

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
select tn.trans_date, tn.with as wit1, stn.with as wit2 
FROM fn_trans AS tn 
LEFT JOIN fn_sub_trans AS stn ON stn.L_trans_id = tn.trans_id 
WHERE tn.L_cat_id IN (11,12) OR stn.L_cat_id in (11,12)
```

This returns a table

```
trans_date  wit1        wit2    
2023-06-14  50.0000     12.0000
2023-06-14  50.0000     13.0000
2023-05-08  16.0000     NULL
2023-04-29  13.5000     NULL
2023-04-28  65.6000     NULL
```

Can I make it so the columns that have data from wit2 replace whats in wit1?  So basically the 12 and 13 would replace the 50s.  But I want to keep the rest of the wit1 colum where the wit2 fields are NULL

Comment: maybe you are looking for the `COALESCE()` function. `select tn.trans_date, tn.with as wit1, stn.with as wit2, COALESCE(stn.with, tn.with) as wit3 ...`

Comment: *Can I make it so the columns that have data from wit2 replace whats in wit1? So basically the 12 and 13 would replace the 50s. But I want to keep the rest of the wit1 colum where the wit2 fields are NULL* Simply do not use LEFT joining, use INNER one.